# Vue File Upload with Parameters

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core, axios

Hi Guys i create a component to upload files and its working so far, but along with the data I'll like to pass some parameters too, for example

HTML

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="large-12 medium-12 small-12 cell">
          <label>
            Files
      v-on:click="upload()">Submit</v-btn>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Script

```js
import
          axios.post('/api/upload', this.files)
      .then(resuta);
    }, error => {
      console.error(error);
    });
  }
```

here (axios.post('/api/upload', this.files)) i would like to include
**email: this.profile.email**

Because I'm adding this parameter to the file name on my backend

Controller

```c#
[HttpPost, DisableRequestSizeLimit]
    public ActionResult UploadFile(string email)
    {

        var files = Request.Form.Files;
        foreach (var file in files)
        {

                }
            }

        }
        return Ok();
    }
```

Comment: What is `this.files`? Also, your `fileChange` method is missing its argument list

Comment: this.files is  data() {
      return {
        records: [],
        application: [],
        profile: [],
        files: new FormData()

Comment: How can `profile` be an array **and** have a `.email` property? Where does `profile.email` come from and when / where is it assigned a value? Does that value ever change once it's assigned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given `this.files` is a [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) instance, you should be able to [set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/set) any field you want. For example

```js
upload () {
  this.files.set('email', this.profile.email)

  axios.post('/api/upload', this.files)...
```

I don't know .NET MVC very well any more but this would add `email` as a form param in the request.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this way;

```
HttpContext.Request.Form.Where(p => p.Key == "email").FirstOrDefault().Value;
```